# list items width not extending to contain contents when whitespace-nowrap is set and parent overflow-x-auto

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

How can I make the first li tag have the same width as the contents?

How can I make the other li tags have the same width as the first one?

I need the overflow-auto in the parent to show the horizontal scrollbar.

Is it possible to achieve this with pure CSS? and using tailwind?

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<ul class="overflow-x-auto w-32">
  <li class="bg-blue-50 whitespace-nowrap">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget hendrerit nibh.
  </li>
  <li class="bg-red-50 whitespace-nowrap">foo</li>
  <li class="bg-green-50 whitespace-nowrap">bar</li>
  <li class="bg-orange-50 whitespace-nowrap">baz</li>
 <ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution without js:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="w-32 overflow-x-auto">
<ul class="w-min">
  <li class="bg-blue-50 whitespace-nowrap">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget hendrerit nibh.
  </li>
  <li class="bg-red-50 whitespace-nowrap">foo</li>
  <li class="bg-green-50 whitespace-nowrap">bar</li>
  <li class="bg-orange-50 whitespace-nowrap">baz</li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Set `inline-block` display for the `<li>` tags: This allows each `<li>` to
occupy only the necessary `width` based on its contents.

**2.** Calculate the `width` of the first `<li>` tag dynamically:
Use JavaScript to get the width of the first `<li>` tag after it has been rendered and then apply that `width` to all other `<li>` tags.

Here is how you can modify your code and add some JavaScript to achieve this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<ul class="overflow-x-auto max-w-full">
  <li id="firstLi" class="bg-blue-50 whitespace-nowrap inline-block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget hendrerit nibh.
  </li>
  <li class="bg-red-50 whitespace-nowrap inline-block">foo</li>
  <li class="bg-green-50 whitespace-nowrap inline-block">bar</li>
  <li class="bg-orange-50 whitespace-nowrap inline-block">baz</li>
</ul>

<script>
  // Get the width of the first li element
  const firstLi = document.getElementById('firstLi');
  const firstLiWidth = firstLi.offsetWidth;

  // Set the width of all li elements to match the width of the first one
  const allLiElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  allLiElements.forEach(li => {
    li.style.width = `${firstLiWidth}px`;
  });
</script>
```

In this code:

- I've added the `inline-block` class to each `<li>` element to make them inline-block elements, so they take up only as much width as necessary/content.
- I've wrapped the `<li>` elements inside a `<ul>` element with `overflow-x-auto` and `max-w-full` classes to enable horizontal scrolling and ensure the list takes up the full width of its container.

**NOTE:** JavaScript code calculates the width of the first `<li>` element and then applies that width to all other `<li>` elements, ensuring they have the same width.

I executed the code and go this output:

[li and other having same width and horizontal scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8ncn.png)

and after adding more content to first `<li>` got the following output as:

[after adding content & scroll proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NbJG.png)

Like it if you find it helpful so others can use it too.

Happy Coding and have a good day❤️